# How to unlock tables using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I use the mysql statement "UNLOCK TABLES" using mysqli in php? I can't put it at the end the existing statement just by using a semi-colon, I get an error doing it that way. Here's what I tried to do "UPDATE blah blah; UNLOCK TABLES;" then I tried to execute it but it won't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE blah blah");
$mysqli->query("UNLOCK TABLES");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

$sql = "UPDATE blah blah";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
        
mysqli_query($connection , "UNLOCK TABLES;");
```